# How to use auto install chromedriver in IIS server?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, iis

When running directly in pychram selenium, chrome driver (ChromeDriverManager().install()) install successful.

But when host in iis server getting access denied.

Here is the code

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))`

Error Message

> webdriver closed.... [WinError 5] Access is denied:
> "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.wdm"

Please Give me Some Tips..

I was trying Manual download chrome driver path.
But I need Auto Install in IIS server.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v4.6*** and above [**Selenium Manager**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76563271/7429447) would take care of downloading the matching *chromedriver* binary. So your effective line of code will be:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Comment: I Have Using Same version 4.6.0 but getting Error
" webdriver closed.... Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver

                                only supports Chrome version 108 Current browser version"

Comment: I want to run in IIS server. can u please check and respond.

Comment: You can refer to another answer of this answerer about this error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71086902/20058276.